# Add data attribute to radio buttons using simple_form.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm trying to distinct data attributes to a radio buttons using simple form.

I want to render the following -

```
<input type="radio" name="special_feature[all_editions]" id="special_feature_all_editions_true" value="true" data-enables="edition_select">
<input type="radio" name="special_feature[all_editions]" id="special_feature_all_editions_false" value="false" data-disables="edition_select">


<%= f.input :all_editions,
        as: :radio_buttons
        %>
```

Any idea how I add the differrent data attributes?

Answer (score 1):

```
  form.radio_button(all_editions, txt, :data-data_attr => some_variable)
```

or

```
<%= f.input :all_editions,
        as: :radio_buttons,
       'data-data_attr' => 'some_variable'
%>
```

Comment: And what if i pass a collection to the radio buttons, how can i set the data attribute depending on the collection value? = form.input :zip, :as => :radio, :collection => Zip.all, :'data-enable_dropdown' => '??'